How to interpret android studio emulator logcat
I run on the android studio emulator an apk file that I built before, it crashes almost instantly but I can't get why it happens
2024-05-18 18:25:22.383   209-212   android.sy....0-service android.system.suspend@1.0-service   E  Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2024-05-18 18:25:22.390   209-212   android.sy....0-service android.system.suspend@1.0-service   E  Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2024-05-18 18:25:25.279  6815-6815  ython_wialon_v          pid-6815                             E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2024-05-18 18:25:25.776   371-371   Layer                   surfaceflinger                       E  [Surface(name=Task=1)/@0x9e73509 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
2024-05-18 18:25:25.776   371-371   Layer                   surfaceflinger                       E  [Surface(name=Task=1)/@0x9e73509 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
2024-05-18 18:25:25.776   371-371   Layer                   surfaceflinger                       E  [Surface(name=Task=23)/@0x729e197 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
2024-05-18 18:25:25.776   371-371   Layer                   surfaceflinger                       E  [Surface(name=Task=23)/@0x729e197 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
2024-05-18 18:25:31.829   538-644   InputDispatcher         system_server                        E  channel '5bc977f com.flet.python_wialon_v2/com.flet.python_wialon_v2.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2024-05-18 18:25:37.489   209-212   android.sy....0-service android.system.suspend@1.0-service   E  Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2024-05-18 18:25:37.497   209-212   android.sy....0-service android.system.suspend@1.0-service   E  Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2024-05-18 18:25:48.259   461-461   netmgr                  netmgr                               E  qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2024-05-18 18:25:48.259   461-461   netmgr                  netmgr                               E  Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2024-05-18 18:25:48.329   470-470   wifi_forwarder          wifi_forwarder                       E  qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2024-05-18 18:25:48.330   470-470   wifi_forwarder          wifi_forwarder                       E  RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe

The apk file was built using python flet so I simply re-built another file but obviously it didn't work... I wonder there are some problems with the source code but I'm not able to read the logcat

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

First you forgot zk tell us the packageName of your app. The shown logcat does not contain any entry related to your app. Are you sure you extracted the correct time span?
